# Running Windows Server as a virtual server on a Mac

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualization, osx-server

I'm looking to virtualize an instance of Server 2003 on OS X as a service rather than a client application. I've been trawling through the web but it seems to be users looking to set up a local server for testing purposes on their laptop/desktop rather than a proper full Server 2003/2008 install.

Ideally, I'd like this to behave like Hyper-V or other bare-metal virtualization software, where the virtual machine would start at machine boot and run in the background without any user intervention.

What are my options for making this work?

Comment: Hyper-V won't run on Mac.  I'd take a look at the VMWare solutions, but product recommendations are off-topic here on SuperUser.

Comment: You won't be able to use Hyper-V from within OS X.  You can either boot to Windows Server and have Hyper-V as an option or use some other virtual machine.  There is no solution to get Hyper-V running from within OS X.

Comment: I was just using Hyper-V as an example. Ideally I'd rather not have to login & boot up virtual machines in order to access the windows based apps I need.

Comment: [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is a great free virtualization solution which runs on OS X.

Comment: @ScottMcGready - So use the virtual machine software of your choice.  You have 3 major choices, one is free, the other two cost money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VirtualBox and `launchd` to launch VMs at boot as daemons.  See [here](http://rcaguilar.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/auto-starting-virtualbox-vms-on-os-x/) for one such example that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Just downloaded VirtualBox and started the long installation process. Seems like the best option (using `launchd`) and VirtualBox ticks all my boxes.

Comment: Went with VirtualBox, installed Server 2003 without issues, runs exactly as expected using `launchd`.

Comment: glad to hear it!